# What is wrong with My Apache2 (Alternate) 000-default.conf file

Tags: server, apache2, php

I'm starting a course in PHP which will require its own web-pages that I do not want to conflict with my existing work. The Ubuntu instructions are here: [HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/httpd.html#https-configuration)

See the code below in my new "/etc/apache2/sites-available/RecipeCenter". The old "/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf" still exists. The only difference between the two versions is the line for document root, which was changed from "/var/www/html" to "/var/www/RecipeCenter" in the new file as shown below. After following the instructions, I also ran the update program and restart. No error messages were generated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/RecipeCenter

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Entering "localhost/RecipeCenter/testph2.php" into the firefox browser did not work.
However, as a test, I did copy the RecipeCenter folder into the same folder as my default folder so I was able to get "localhost/RecipeCenter/testph.php" to work. While that solves the problem, I still have an unanswered concern with why the new .conf file did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should symlink your /etc/apache2/sites-available/RecipeCenter to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-RecipeCenter.conf. (The number doesn't matter too much, though the files are included in alphabetical order, so whatever name you choose for the symlink, it should alphabetically come after 000-default.conf.

Apache actually includes vhost config files from /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. It doesn't include sites-available. The structure is made up like this to allow you to easily enable/disable sites by creating/deleting symlinks in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, without the need to move or remove files.